# Delete Last X Number of Sheets Using Google App Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I need to delete the last x number of sheets (tabs) from a spreadsheet (workbook) using Google App Script. All I have been able to scrounge up through Googling is this bit of code, which does not do what I need.

```js
function DeleteSheet() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  spreadsheet.deleteActiveSheet();}
};
```

This obviously deletes the first X number of sheets (tabs) at the beginning of a spreadsheet. What I need is a similar script that will delete the last x number of sheets at the end of a spreadsheet. In other words I need to delete sheets from right to left rather than from left to right as is done in the code above.

Below is the exact code that I need in a vba format, but I don't know how to write it appropriately in Google App Script.

```vba
Sub DeleteAll()
    i = Worksheets.Count
    For x = i to 21 Step -1 '# <- please note the change here
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        Worksheets(x).Delete
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Next x
End Sub
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
function delete_sheets() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheets = spreadsheet.getSheets();
  var len = sheets.length;
  for (var i = len-1; i > len-11; i--) spreadsheet.deleteSheet(sheets[i]);
}
```

Another variant:

```
function delete_sheets() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheets = spreadsheet.getSheets();
  var x = 10;
  while (x--) spreadsheet.deleteSheet(sheets.pop());
}
```

Comment: How would I modify this *while* loop to ignore sheets with a specific name? I can't for the life of me figure this out. I have tried it 100 different ways, and they all fail. Thanks in advance for anyone that can help!

Comment: Not sure if the 'while' variant is suitable for this task. I'd advice to modify the 'for' variant. You can just add the condition: `if (sheets[i].getName() != 'name1'  && sheets[i].getName() != 'name2')` something like this. If there are more than two names you can make the array of names (`var names = ['name1', 'name2', 'name3']`) and check if the sheet's name exists/not-exists in this array this way: `if (names.includes(sheets[i].getName()) == false)`